# java.lang.NullPointerException:Attempt to invoke virtual method android.content.pm.PackageManager android.content.Context.getPackageManager()

Tags: android

> Getting exception "java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke
> virtual method 'android.content.pm.PackageManager
> android.content.Context.getPackageManager()' on a null object
> reference"

when i execute below code.
Goal: change image dynamically based on some status for one flavor in android studio.

AndroidManifest.xml

```
 <application
        tools:replace="android:icon,android:roundIcon"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="${appIcon}"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="${appIconRound}"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name="devicelist.AddDeviceActivity"/>
        <activity android:name="resourcestatesimulator.NativeActivity" />
        <activity android:name="devicelist.DeviceListActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="CarplayMain" />

        <activity-alias
            android:name=".DeviceListActivityAlias"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_default"
            android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_default_round"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:targetActivity="devicelist.DeviceListActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity-alias>
    </application>
```

DeviceListActivity.java

```
public void defaultIcon()
    {
        Log.i(TAG, "Before default Icon" );
        packageManager = getPackageManager();
        packageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(new ComponentName(DeviceListActivity.this,"com.bosch.spi.carplay.devicelist.DeviceListActivity"),
                PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
                PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);

        packageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(new ComponentName(DeviceListActivity.this,"com.bosch.spi.carplay.devicelist.DeviceListActivityAlias"),
                PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
                PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
        Log.i(TAG, "After default Icon" );
    }
    public void activeIcon()
    {
        Log.i(TAG, "Before active Icon" );
        packageManager = getPackageManager();
        packageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(new ComponentName(DeviceListActivity.this,"com.bosch.spi.carplay.devicelist.DeviceListActivity"),
                PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
                PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);

        packageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(new ComponentName(DeviceListActivity.this,"com.bosch.spi.carplay.devicelist.DeviceListActivityAlias"),
                PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
                PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
        Log.i(TAG, "After Active Icon" );
    }
```

Calling methods in DeviceListAdapter.java

```
DeviceListActivity deviceListActivity= new DeviceListActivity();
deviceListActivity.activeIcon();
deviceListActivity.defaultIcon();
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: No my question is totally different. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem happens because you are trying to manually instantiate the Activity `DeviceListActivity`. When you call `getPackageManager()` inside the methods from `DeviceListActivity` class it throws a `NullPointerException` because your activity is not managed by Android so it don't know how to provide a package manger for it since Android runtime don't even know about your `deviceListActivity` since you have instantiated it with `new` keyword. Don't do this.
You have to let Android manage your Activities for you, never instantiate it with `new` keyword.

Read [this](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity) to understand the proper way to start an activity.

Comment: My requirement is to call activeIcon() and defaultIcon() in another java file.How to achieve?

Comment: But why do you need to call those methods? In order for me to be able to help, you need to provide more info. What are you trying to do? DeviceListActivity is your main activity, so in runtime, this is the first activity that should open. In what moment you want to call those methods and why?

Comment: Requirement:  Change app icon based on carplay connection status for one flavor.AndroidManifest.xml and code changes are given in post. My connectionstatus logic in defined in DeviceListAdapter.java and my activity in xml is DeviceListActivity.java.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you intend to do. I don't know what is "carplay connetion status" for you and what its connection to Android programming. If you really want help with whatever you want to do, you have to better communicate it. I have already explained the reason you are getting a `NullPointerException` and what is wrong with your code. But I don't know what your DeviceListAdapter do, where is its entry point on the application and why you are trying to instantiate DeviceListActivity from it. Without this info, I can't help.